# Row of anchors that I want to make into two rows?

Tags: html, css

I have a row of 7 anchor links. I want to get the 4th anchor and push it onto the row below, but whatever I do I get the 4th anchor pushed onto the row below, and the last 3 anchors then jump to the row below again.

```css
.linkSpan a:nth-child(4) {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<span class="linkSpan">
    <a href="#">item</a>
    <a href="#">item</a>
    <a href="#">item</a>
    <a href="#">item</a>
    <a href="#">item</a>
    <a href="#">item</a>
    <a href="#">item</a>
</span>
```

How do I  get the reset of anchors up beside the 4th anchor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the links to float, and clear float on the particular item.

```css
.linkSpan {
    overflow: auto;
}
.linkSpan a {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4px;
}
.linkSpan a:nth-child(4) {
    clear: left;
}
```

```html
<span class="linkSpan">
    <a href="#">item</a>
    <a href="#">item</a>
    <a href="#">item</a>
    <a href="#">item</a>
    <a href="#">item</a>
    <a href="#">item</a>
    <a href="#">item</a>
</span>
```

Or add pseudo element to force a line break.

```css
.linkSpan a:nth-child(4):before {
    content: "";
    display: table;
}
```

```html
<span class="linkSpan">
    <a href="#">item</a>
    <a href="#">item</a>
    <a href="#">item</a>
    <a href="#">item</a>
    <a href="#">item</a>
    <a href="#">item</a>
    <a href="#">item</a>
</span>
```

Comment: Perfect, your first solution worked like a charm. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 2):

What about something like this: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/yNPvXb

```
a:nth-child(4)::before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: I'll try this approach as it does what I want

Comment: This is doing nothing to the layout, would the fact that there is a span enclosing the links affect the css? I have a class for the span which I am using, so it's:

.linkSpan a:nth-child(4)::before